# Difference betweeen Fix and Edit in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame having 1000 rows.I can use fix command or edit command in R to view and edit the data manually.I can't find any difference between the two.
I want to know which is the efficient way of editing the data manually?
Help me out in the same...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fix()` invokes edit on x and then assigns the new version to the same object.

Example:

```
fix(my_dataFrame) #now my_dataFrame is changed
```

In `edit()` - we need to assign it to an object

```
my_new_dataFrame = edit(my_dataFrame)
```

You can read up on them - [edit()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/edit.html) and [fix()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/fix.html)

Answer (score 4):

The difference is pretty trivial:

`edit` lets you edit an object and returns the new version.

`fix` lets you edit an object and modifies the original.

Internally, `fix` pretty much does the following:

- Retrieve the name of the variable passed to `fix` (call it `name`)
- Invoke `result = edit(original)`
- Invoke `assign(name, result, .GlobalEnv)`